# How to separately edit multiple discord embeds?

Tags: discord.js, embed

I created a discord bot with the goal to generate reactive embeds with emoji-buttons. My problem is all the embeds created with the bot are modified simultaneously once a 'button' is pressed.

Below a pseudo-code of my bot:

```
const raidEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed() //create the embed
//some code to fill the embed

message.channel.send(raidEmbed).then(embedMessage => {
    embedMessage.react('❌')
    .then(()=>embedMessage.react('⭕')
    //more react to create all the 'buttons'

    client.on('messageReactionAdd', (reaction, user) => {
       //some code to do stuff when the right 'button' is pressed
       //then reset the button with this code:
       if (user.id !== client.user.id) {
           reaction.users.remove(user.id);
       }
 
       const newEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
       //code to create the new embed
       embedMessage.edit(newEmbed);
    }
})
```

I don't understand why all my embeds are linked together and how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your embeds are not all linked together. The issue here is that you are using a global event to check for reactions. This is the part of your code that is the issue:

```
client.on('messageReactionAdd', (reaction, user) => {
   //some code to do stuff when the right 'button' is pressed
   //then reset the button with this code:
   if (user.id !== client.user.id) {
       reaction.users.remove(user.id);
   }

   const newEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
   //code to create the new embed
   embedMessage.edit(newEmbed);
}
```

What this part of your code is doing is *whenever* a reaction is added to *any* message, *all* of your embeds are edited. This means that even adding a reaction to a message that is not an embed will cause all of your embeds to be modified. `messageReactionAdd` is a global event, meaning it applies to *all* messages, not just your embed messages.

The best solution is to use a [reaction collector](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=createReactionCollector) instead of a reaction event. Reaction collectors are created on specific messages, so only the embed you reacted on will be modified.

Here is an example with your code, it may not necessarily be a working example but it should give you a general idea of how to accomplish this:

```
const raidEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed() //create the embed
//some code to fill the embed

message.channel.send(raidEmbed).then(embedMessage => {
    embedMessage.react('❌')
    .then(()=>embedMessage.react('⭕')
    //more react to create all the 'buttons'

    const filter = (reaction, user) => (r.emoji.name == "❌" || r.emoji.name == "⭕") && user.id === message.author.id;
    const collector = embedMessage.createReactionCollector(filter, { time: 15000 });
    collector.on('collect', reaction => {

        //some code to do stuff when the right 'button' is pressed
        //then reset the button with this code:
        reaction.users.remove(message.author.id);

        const newEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        //code to create the new embed
        embedMessage.edit(newEmbed);
    }

})
```

You can also use the `filter` to narrow down which users' reactions should be collected as well as what specific reactions you want to collect.

Comment: Ty for your explanations :)
I modified your code to answer my needs and it works just fine !
(apart r.emoji.name which should be reaction.emoji.name) :

```const filter = (reaction) => (reaction.emoji.name == "❌" || reaction.emoji.name == "⭕");
    const collector = embedMessage.createReactionCollector(filter);
    collector.on('collect', (reaction, user) => {```